# Correct way to work with future objects within multiple Future builder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

For example I have a late future object with news list within a StatefulWidget

```
late Future<List<News>> loadedList;
```

I need to use this loadedNewsList outside of Future.builder in some methods like that (this code will fail as far loadedList is not inited yet)

```
  void markLoadedAsRead() async {
    String _time = DateTime.now().toString();

    for (var el in loadedList!) {
      if(el.readAt == null){
        el.readAt = _time;
        final _n = await DatabaseHelper.instance.findNews(el.uuid);
        if(_n == null) {
          await DatabaseHelper.instance.insertNews(el);
        } else {
          await DatabaseHelper.instance.updateNews(el);
        }
      }
    }
    setState((){});
  }
```

And also I want some inerface Future.builders to be aware loadedList is loaded like that. Appbar example that is shown only when loadedList is completed.

```
actions: <Widget>[
          FutureBuilder<List<News>>(
            future: loadedList, // a Future<String> or null
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) developer.log(snapshot.error.toString());
                if (!snapshot.hasData) return const SizedBox.shrink();

                return IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_list_alt),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    developer.log('FEED smooth scroll news to top before filter click');
                    _scrollToTop();
                    // disposeAd();
                    await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => const FilterPage()));
                    // getBanner();
                    developer.log('FEED call news after filter page visit');
                    // await fetchNews(false);
                    // setState(() {});
                  },
                );
              }
          )
        ]
```

So, what is the correct way to handle that in Flutter?

Comment: move your future builder up the widget tree, so it stays above all places you need this future

Comment: It's already done this way. All the Future.builders receive loadedList properly. But I cannot iterate through Future<List<News>>  loadedList  as through List<News> inside other functions.

Comment: generally, it is not a good idea to define a global variable for keeping data.
you can use a state management approach to set and modify `loadedList`.

Comment: Yes, Hamed, my production is done this way but it looks totally lame. So, I was curious about how to do it correct.